# Is there a name for a random variable that is the absolute value of the difference between two iid discrete uniform variables?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, terminology

I'm working on a project and I needed to calculate the distribution of the difference between two iid discrete uniform variables (sorry for the long title).
That is, let $I, J$ be two iid discrete uniform variables with support $\{1, \ldots, k\}$. I calculated the distribution of $Z = |I - J|$:
$P(Z = 0) = \frac{1}{k}$, $P(Z = y) = \frac{2(k-y)}{k^2}\ \forall y \in \{1, \ldots, k-1\}$.
I was wondering if such a distribution has a name, so that I can get more info and maybe some results about it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: this is called a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution)

Comment: Thanks @CarloBeenakker. I see how that distribution is similar, but I don't exactly understand how you would discretize it to yield the distribution I calculated...

Comment: This is not a discrete triangular distribution, since the probability that the difference is 0 is roughly half the probability that it is 1.

Comment: The random variable $I-J$ could be called "discrete triangular"; it is centered at zero. But the poster asks for the absolute value of that, namely $Z=|I-J|$.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't have a (very known) name and "absolute value of a discrete triangular random variable" is good enough. Thank you all anyway. :)